# How do I split a big PR in to multiple small PRs ? basically rolling back the video film roll in time lapse mode

Tags: git, cucumber

I have raised a big git PR with say 45 test stories (we are using Java Cucumber BDD) in a single branch. Say these 45 stories belong to 3 categories like Users, Device, Bootload etc., equally like each category has 15 stories implemented. Each test story implementation happens in 3 files,

1. feature file
2. BDD steps file,
3. BDD step implementation file.
   Each category(of test cases) will have above separately named 3 implementation files.

Our Manager wanted this big PR with 45 stories in a single branch to be split in to ideally 45 PRs, or in my idea is to raise at least 15 PRs, each PR containing implementation of 3 stories each.

So with this in mind, now I start with the pristine 'master' branch, start a new branch-CA1 (meaning development branch for CategoryA, branch 1).

Then following in the same lines, I will have

- branches-CA2, CA3, CA4, CA5 FOR category A,
- branches-CB1, CB2, CB3, CB4, CB5 FOR category B,
- branches-CC1, CC2, CC3, CC4, CB5 FOR category C

Each of those branches will start from the pulling of pristine 'master' branch and
CA1, CA2, CA3, CA4, CA5 will change(**append one story implementation after another**) the same 3 implementation files mentioned above.

Similarly so does CB1, CB2, CB3, CB4, CB5 will change(append one story implementation after another) the same 3 implementation files(**names different corresponding to the Category B**) mentioned above.

Similarly so does CC1, CC2, CC3, CC4, CC5 will change(append one story implementation after another) the same 3 implementation files(**names different corresponding to the Category C**) mentioned above.

Now would there be a problem after raising 15 smaller PRs with 3 stories each, instead of big blob of 1 PR with 45 stories. How do I think that ??

When the 1st PR of Category A, having first 3 story implementations..... until 15th PR of Category C, having the last of 43,44,45th test story implementations.

When these PRs tried to be merged in sequence **after some review comments and their remediation for each PR**, how well the subsequent PRs merging will end up ? Do they have innumerable no. of conflicts, as each PR is built on top of a pristine master branch even though each story implementation is atomically and individually change the 3 implementation files in sequence ?

Is there a better approach ? It is due to our PR reviewer guy wining about unable to review a big bundle of 45 stories at a time over a long time like a day instead of small PR(with 3 stories) review which may take hardly an hour or less.

Comment: Do the stories depend on each other / modify the same files? If not, you could do a soft reset to the point where you branched off of master and create multiple different commits  (on different branches) that each bundle one or several stories. For next time: try to create smaller PRs and get the reviewed and merged individually. You will be able to fix merge conflicts for stuff you just worked on (more easily than these large PRs anyway). Good luck!

Comment: Yes, In each category they do and modify the same set of 3 files, I mentioned.
If I reset to the original point(pristine) where I started off, I selectively copy and paste the code for each small PR from my back up of code files, thus proceed to raise all the PRs (45 in total) across 3 categories, I would have to start each PR from the start point (pristine condition of master). Right ? Then when each small PR(1 to 45) gets reviewed and any corrections done in each PR, would they not lead to a lot of conflicts which I need to carry always across all the PRs ?

Comment: If they all change the same files you would in fact have to redo them as there is no easy way to recommit them as different sets of files per PR. Next suggestion: did you do separate commits per story? if so, suggest them to be reviewed per commit? (if needed, you can squash multiple commits for same story together).